# Can't import axios to chrome extension background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, import, axios

I'm trying to import the axios module to the background script of a chrome extension and I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './node_modules/axios/lib/axios.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

Since chrome extensions need to use the script tag to use external modules, I'm doing it the following way:

#### manifest.json

```
"background": {
  "page": "background.html",
  "persistent": false
},
...
```

#### background.html

```
<script type="module" src="./background.js"></script>
```

#### background.js

```
import axios from './node_modules/axios/lib/axios.js';
...
```

I also tried to use the named import with the code below but got a similar message (the 'default' was switched with 'axios')

```
import { axios } from './node_modules/axios/lib/axios.js';
```

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory so it's useless to import it as a ES module directly in the browser. You may need to use a bundler/compiler such as webpack. Or just load the script normally without modules and simply use `axios` global. Refer to the documention and usage examples for axios.